# Data deleted with IN clause even if the column doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

So, here is the test query you could play with:

```
select top 10 * into #tmp FROM A
delete from #tmp WHERE xxx_id in (select xxx_id FROM B)
```

Actually, all these 10 records are deleted. The question is why are these 10 records deleted?

Note: `xxx_id` is one column in table `A` only, it doesn't exist in table `B`. But the delete statement "works" anyway.

Here's a demonstration of this behaviour: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/963f9/1/1

### Update

I found the answer in MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/418722dc-a7bf-44c5-a2f6-e8d1cd00dbdc/in-clause-ignores-error-in-subquery-possible-bug?forum=transactsql
Actually, the MSSQL tried to blind the `xxx_id` to table `B` in subquery, if not found, it tries to blind it to table `A`. So, the query equals:

```
delete from #tmp WHERE xxx_id = xxx_id
```

and all data was deleted.

Comment: Did you intend to post this somewhere else? It seems you're addressing someone in particular "here is the test query you could play with". And what do you mean by "handle this script"? It executes it. Does it not do what you intended? If so, what did you want it to do and why?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, I am just trying to post one test query so that anyone who're interested could have a try. Sorry if it makes any confusion. Actually, I would expected an error as column `xxx_id` doesn't exist in table `B`.

Comment: The explanation for your delete statement is that it will look up the `xxx_id` field it finds on a row in `#tmp` in `B`, and if that value is found there, the row in `#tmp` will be deleted. So, if all 10 id's are found, all the rows will be deleted.

Comment: Table `B` is not really a necessary. It could be any other table without `xxx_id` column.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's what I am confused. It will say error if I query `select xxx_id from B` but it doesn't if I run above query.

Comment: @zhongxiao37: now i get it, btw. here is the related sql-fiddle to demonstrate it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86379/1/1 I've edited your question to include it.

Comment: It's a really good habit to get into to *always* specify columns as `tablename.columnname` (or `tablealias.columnname`). It doesn't completely prevent the issue (you could accidentally use the outer table alias) but it will catch this 99% of the time.

Comment: @zhongxiao37: my fiddle was broken, this is the correct one (edited it already into your question): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/963f9/1/1

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter. I will add an example next time if I have another SQL question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rather well-known behaviour. I'm not saying it's not somewhat unexpected.

The thing is that SQL Server tries to bind names to objects as one of first things id does with the query. With a subquery, it tries to bind columns to tables in the subquery first; if it don't succeed, it will bind columns to tables in outer query.

It's actually an excellent reason to always use aliases with tables.

Answer (score 0):

To check which kind of rows are deleted from A, you can query

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE xxx_id IN (SELECT xxx_id FROM B)
```

To check what values are in sub query (SELECT xxx_id FROM B), you can query

```
SELECT xxx_id
FROM A, B
```

Which equals to

```
SELECT A.xxx_id,
FROM A, B
```

Now you should know the reason.